# onNewIntent() not called after onResume()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onnewintent

Flow:

1. Open app (MainActivity)
2. Press home button ( calling onPause() in activity )
3. Starting same activity, with different intent

   ```
   Intent intent = Utils.createIntent(....., this, MainActivity.class); // this will add some extra to our intent
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
   ```
4. Nothing happens.
5. onCreate() gets called. (onDestroy wasn't called)
6. onResume() is called

My activity in xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

NOte: if I don't press home button (app doesn't pause), onNewIntent will be called correctly.

Comment: Where is your onRsume code?

Comment: @NiravRanpara I do nothing on onResume. I just set a breakpoint to see if is called.

Comment: i thing android:launchMode="singleTop" is the problem. Try to remove this and check

Comment: Try to set this Flags: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: @VladimirKulyk this fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this Flags:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

---

You are welcome!